# jQuery Select Plugin That Will Allow for Folder/File Structured Tiered Options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

Does anybody know of a jQuery plugin that will allow for what I'm calling "tiered options" within an HTML select element? By this I mean something similar to the folder/file structure system that you find on most Operating Systems. Here's a screen shot of what I'm talking about from Windows:

[tiered select example http://www.glenmorefinancial.com/images/select_example.png](http://www.glenmorefinancial.com/images/select_example.png)

I'm not as much concerned with having the images. Just being able to have a Category and SubCategories within that category are what's important to me.

jQuery is preferred, but if there are any plain javascript options for this, that's cool too.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [one of these](http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/Tree) on for size.

Comment: Thanks. Although this wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it ultimately led me to find the jQuery MultiSelect - http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/multiSelect/demo/ which basically gave me what I needed

Answer (score 2):

This looks nice with support for Option groups

[jQuery UI Selectmenu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)

If you do not mind using `<ul> <li>` You may want to try [these flyout menus](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tree-view plugin: http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/